# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$smt' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$smt' (T_VARIABLE) in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\sytemelogin.php on line 17

```
$smt->bind_param('sssiss',$prenom, $nom, $email, $numero, $Pays,  $condittion);
```

Comment: Please show your code, more than just that one line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: your smt variable is not initialized. How do you create the instance of it?

Comment: You're probably missing a semi-colon on a previous line. Parse/syntax errors usually come from before the line number provided in the error message.

Comment: @ChristianFelix that's not relevant to this syntax error.